# Add an item on DropDownList at client, C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a need to add an item to DropDownList client side, after I made some ajax calls.

If I just use jquery's method to add items to relevant select, it is added there, but when I later select this new (client-side-added) item in dropdown and  do postback, there is a problem:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

How would I **correctly** modify DropDownList, so new entry both appear on list AND if I make postback with that new item selected, its value would go to server and used further?

Comment: The exception message gives you some solid starting points for how to get this done...

Comment: Instead of using and server side control use a select tag and you can modify to you hearts content using JQuery or javascript for example. You won't have all the fancy methods/Properties you have when using a DropDownList but it should do the same job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different strategies that I can suggest.

1. Add any new items to the drop down list server side, call a method on the server via a PostBack to add the new item(s) to the DataSet that the list is bound to and then rebind the drop down list.
2. Bypass the ViewState and get the selected value form the drop down list directly from the post values submitted back to the server as shown below. You would not need to 'round trip' in this case and add the new item(s) server side.

   selectedValue = Request.Form[ - drop down list id -].ToString();

Comment: I'd try second option I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ASP UpdatePanel or you're bound to have trouble with the control being different than what the ViewState tells.

Comment: Yes, that would be the fastest way to solve that problem. FWIW, we are working hard on removing all the update panels we have in our system because they cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: Ok, how exactly I could "use" it in that case? I do not want to reload page to update my Dropdown.